# Text and image side by side with alignment

Tags: html, css

I would like to accomplish the following effect.

```
         -----
         -img-
         -----
--text-- -----
-------- -----
```

Right now, I have the following code:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="pictureFrame"> 
            <img class="picture" src="photo.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="position"> 
            text
        </div>
</div>

<div class="separator"></div>
```

With the following styles:

```
.pictureFrame
{ 
width: 150px;
float: right;
}

.position 
{ 
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.separator
{
clear: both;
}
```

But the vertical align doesn't seem to be working i.e., I get the following,

```
--text-- -----
-------- -----
         -----
         -img-
         -----
```

How to accomplish the desired effect? I apologize if the question is too easy.

Answer (score 1):

Use **position:relative;** on **.header** and **position:absolute;** **bottom:0;** on **div.position;**

You might also need to give div.position a height.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work - the text is still aligned at the top

Answer (score 1):

Float position attribute to the left.

Should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Verical-align property only applies to inline and table-cell elements.

to accomplish this, try removing the wrapping divs, or define them as display inline. However, float won't work with inline elements, so to make the image to follow the text, you will just need to reverse them in your html.

You could also make a fake table-cell, tricking the browser to vertically align. for that, you would need a parent element to be displayed as a table.